# A Daylight Savings Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Within OSI PI, I have been trying to work out a conflict for system times between two systems, one in Daylight Savings Time and the other not.

I have come across a formula that appears to work, though I do not know how.   I though I had created a similar function in excel and had similar success last night, but I did not save my excel file and have not been able to duplicate the success in excel.

Here is the PI formula:

```
Floor(Float('*'-'1-jan') / 3600) Mod 24 <> Hour('*')
```

For those unfamiliar with PI:

- '*' represents current system time.
- Float('*'-'1-jan') gives you the number of seconds from the beginning of the year.
- Floor rounds the value down to the nearest integer.
- Hour('*') gives the current Hour.
- The output is TRUE/FALSE depending whether the datetime value is during Daylight Savings Time.

I modified the formula to allow test dates to be entered:

```
Floor(Float(TestTime-'1-jan') / 3600) Mod 24 <> Hour(TestTime)
```

This allows me to enter any datetime to test (limited to current year only since the '1-jan' is the beginning of the current year).

Other than an error between 2:00 AM and 2:59 AM on 3/11/18, it works.

The system I am running this on is Not on Daylight Savings Time.

My question is:  **Why does this work?**

The current excel versions that DO NOT work:

```
=MOD(FLOOR((VALUE(A2-DATE(YEAR(A2),1,1)) *60*60*24) / 3600,1),24) <> HOUR(A2)

=MOD(FLOOR((VALUE(A2-("Jan1"+0)) *60*60*24) / 3600,1),24) <> HOUR(A2)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the fact you are getting an error on 3/11/18, I am *assuming* that you're in America, and the error is 11th March (US Daylight saving: 2018-03-11 to 2018-11-04) and not Europe (2018-03-25 to 2018-10-28) or South-west Australia (2017-10-01 to 2018-04-01).

In PI, you get the seconds since the year started - divide this by 3600 (to get hours) and `Floor` it (to get *whole* hours), then `mod 24` to remove all the complete 24-hour cycles.  Then, compare that against the hour of time you are checking:  during Daylight Saving, there is a 'missing' hour, (a 23-hour day) which gets added back on when you leave it again (a 25-hour day).

Excel deals with Dates as Days, rather than Seconds.  So, `"2018-01-01 12:00" - "2018-01-01 00:00"` will give `0.5` instead of `43200`.  Try checking what result you get for `=ROUND("2018-03-12 12:00"-"2018-03-10 12:00",3)` - is it `2.000` or `1.958`?  If the former, you'll need to find another method to do this.  If the **latter**, use `=MOD(INT((A2-DATE(Year(A2), 1, 1))*24), 24) <> Hour(A2)`

Comment: Correct.   I am in the Mountain Daylight Time in the USA.   I assume the error between 2:00 AM and 3:00 AM is because when switching to DST, there is nothing between 1:59:59 AM and 3:00 AM.   However, as the server running the formula is in Arizona (no Daylight Savings Time), I'm not sure why the formula would actually work.   I'll try your modifications to the excel formula.